# Add Selected Users Ids to List Instead of Position in Android

Tags: java, android, list, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I am trying to make a contacts list, where the user can select multiple contacts and add them to a list. Right now when I click on a contact I get number of selected contacts, user Id, and a list that displays ***selected user's position***. What ***I want*** to do is ***to display selected user's id and add it to my list***, instead of position. I am going by [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/) tutorial.

My ChooseContactsAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ChooseContactsAdapter.ChooseContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    holder.userName.setText(contact.getUserName());

    TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .withBorder(0)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .round();

    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
//  generate color based on a key (same key returns the same color), useful for list/grid views
    int color = generator.getColor(contact.getUserId());
    textDrawable = builder.build(contactList.get(position).getUserName().substring(0, 1), color);
    holder.thumbNail.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
 // THIS IS WHERE I GET MY USER ID FROM THE HOLDER
    holder.contactId = contact.getUserId();
    // display profile image
    applyProfilePicture(holder, contact);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // toggle selection
            toggleSelection(position);

            // Change background color of the selected items in list view
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(selectedItems.get(position) ? context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ppdColorOrangeSelection) : Color.TRANSPARENT);

            // check if item still exists
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Contact contact = contactList.get(position);
              // THIS TOAST IS WHERE I DISPLAY MY STUFF ON CLICK 
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + holder.contactId + ", number of selected contacts is " + getSelectedItemCount() + ", contacts id's are " + getSelectedItems(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // applyIconAnimation(holder, position);
            }

            // change the row state to activated
            //holder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));
            // handle icon animation
            applyIconAnimation(holder, position);
            // apply click events
            //applyClickEvents(holder, position);
            // number of selected contacts
            getSelectedItemCount();
            // selected contacts
            getSelectedItems();
            // reset animation index
            resetAnimationIndex();
            // clear selections
            //clearSelections();
            // number of selected contacts
            getSelectedItemCount();
        }
    });
}

private List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    List<Integer> items =
            new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
    }

    return items;
}

// adding user ids to list
private List<Integer> getSelectedUserIds() {
    List<Integer> items =
            new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
    }

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This is what I needed to add to my code.

Adapter:

```
if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
    Contact contact = contactList.get(position);
    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + holder.contactId + ", number of selected contacts is " + getSelectedItemCount() + ", contacts id's are " + getSelectedUserIds(holder.contactId = contact.getUserId(), position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    applyIconAnimation(holder, position);
    String userId = contact.getUserId();

    // Adding/removing user ids to list
    if (!selectedIds.contains(userId)) {
        selectedIds.add(userId);
    } else {
        selectedIds.remove(userId);
    }
}
```

I called it in my Activity like this:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedIds = adapter.selectedIds;
```